# how to fix php curl extension error while installing magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, extensions, curl

How to fix php curl extension error while installing magento 2?

I attached the **Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Downgrading PHP version from 7.2.14 to 7.1.26 in Wamp fixed the issue. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

### You can check if curl is enabled in your PHP installation by reviewing a phpinfo() file.

```
And if it's not installed.
```

**Use the following steps to install curl:**

1. Open https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz?type=bin in a browser.
2. Select your operating system in the dropdown box: either Windows
   /Win32 or Win 64. Click Select!
3. For Win 32, choose whether you will use curl in a Windows Command
   Prompt (Generic) or in a Cygwin terminal (cygwin). For Win 64,
   choose whether you will use curl in a Windows Command Prompt
   (Generic) or MinGW (MinGW64). Click Select!
4. If required, choose your Windows operating system. Finish.
5. Click Download for the version which has SSL enabled or disabled
6. Open the downloaded zip file. Extract the files to an easy-to-find
   place, such as C:\Program Files.

**Testing curl**

1. Open up the Windows Command Prompt terminal. (From the Start menu,
   click Run, then type cmd.)
2. Set the path to include the directory where you put curl.exe. For
   example, if you put it in C:\Program Files\curl, then you would type
   the following command: set path=%path%;"c:\Program Files\curl"

**NOTE:** You can also directly copy the curl.exe file any existing path in your path

Type curl. You should see the following message: curl: try 'curl –help' or 'curl –message' for more information This means that curl is installed and the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the line in the php.ini file: `;extension=php_curl.dll`

Remove ; at the beginning of this line. And you may need to restart apache server.

Comment: I am using windows 7 64 bit operating system

Comment: You should mention all the details in your questions correctly. Check my updated answer.

Comment: The line was uncommenting already...... but not working @Shireen N

Answer (score 0):

The steps are as follows :

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\php\(your version of php)\`
3. Edit `php.ini`
4. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
5. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\Apache\(your version of apache)\bin\`
6. Edit `php.ini`
7. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: Uncomment already but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have wamp server**

> Please review screen shot and try given setting than restart your Wamp server.

[image]

Comment: it was checked already